# Tomcat: configure VM properties

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to configure some VM properties for our web application. What is the *right* place to do this on a Tomcat 7.0 server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit or create `setenv.sh` (located in `/bin` directory) to set your custom settings, `catalina.sh` will pick it up automatically.(don't edit catalina.sh!)

For Tomcat specific tuning use `CATALINA_OPTS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS`

UPDATE:
 Forgot to ask you the platform you are using, if it's `Windows` use `setenv.bat` instead of `setenv.sh`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, but now Tomcat fails to start. I just added following line:
`CATALINE_OPTS=-Dfoo=bar` - maybe that's wrong.

Comment: The first line in setenv.sh must be: '#!/bin/sh'. use 'export CATALINA_OPTS=...'

Comment: According to catalina.out (`syntax error near unexpected token `('`) it looks like it does not like a '(' in a value of the VM property.

Comment: can you share setenv.sh or setenv.bat

Comment: It contained a password - after replacing the '(' with a '-' it works.